# RabbitMQ portable on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, erlang, rabbitmq, admin

I do not have access to the admin account in Windows 7. Is there a way to install *RabbitMQ* and its required *Erlang* without admin privileges? In some portable way?

I need to use it in my Python Celery project.

Thanks!

Comment: I know this is an almost year old question that is possibly not relevant to you but I encountered the same thing 6 months ago and I posted an answer. It would be great if you can check that or at least accept it, it's a working solution :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible. Here's how I've done it:

You need to create a portable Erlang and acquire RabbitMQ server files.

- You can install regular Erlang to another computer, then copy the whole installation directory to the computer with limited account. You can use local documents, or AppData like `C:\Users\Limited_Account\AppData\erl5.10.4`
  *(If you don't have any access to another computer, you can extract the setup file with 7-Zip but it'll be troublesome to fix paths.)*
- Modify the erg.ini in the bin folder with the new path. (By default erg.ini uses Unix line endings, so it might be seen as a single line.)

  ```
  [erlang]
  Bindir=C:\\Users\\Limited_Account\\AppData\\erl5.10.4\\erts-5.10.4\\bin
  Progname=erl
  Rootdir=C:\\Users\\Limited_Account\\AppData\\erl5.10.4\\erl5.10.4
  ```
- See if bin\erl.exe opens up Erlang Shell. If you see a crash dump, path might not be correct. If Visual C++ Redist. files were not installed before, it will nag you about msvcr100.dll and you need to manually copy them as well but I don't recommended that.
- Download the zip version of RabbitMQ server from https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows-manual.html and extract it.
- Set %ERLANG_HOME% variable. You can type `set ERLANG_HOME="C:\\Users\\Limited_Account\\AppData\\erl5.10.4\"` in command line. Alternatively, you can add this line to every .bat in the sbin folder.
- Now you can use the management scripts in the sbin folder. For example, you can use rabbitmq_server-3.2.4\sbin\rabbitmq-server.bat to start the RabbitMQ Server. Obviously, starting as a service is not an option because you are not an admin.

For further information, see: https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows-manual.html

Comment: If you use a directory with spaces in the folder name (ex. 'Program Files), use MS-DOS path in .bat files like this: `set ERLANG_HOME="C:\\PROGRA~1\\MY~1\\resources\\assets\\erlang\\erts-10.5"` which corresponds to: `set ERLANG_HOME="C:\\Program Files\\My Folder\\resources\\assets\\erlang\\erts-10.5"`